# getting data from an array of inputs in reactive form in angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[image: Want to get data from both text field and radio button.]

I think Image description is enough for the question. I am beginner in angular.

I am using reactive form, unable to fetch the data from the inputs.

```html
<div *ngIf="isSingleSelection">
  <div class="row">
    <div [formArrayName]="onSingleSelectionArray">
      <div *ngFor="let single of questionForm.get('onSingleSelectionArray').controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="input-group mb-3 col">
            <div class="input-group-prepend mr-2">
              <label> {{i + 1}} </label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="singleOption" name="singleOption" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <input type="radio" formControlName="singleRadio" name="singleRadio" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot get the value of both TEXT and RADIO limited size of 6 elements?

Comment: please include the component code related to the form group and how you are trying to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the code of yours in the following stackblitz and i am getting all the values of the formArray.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rn8hmk?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html

```
get onSingleSelectionArray() {
    return this.formGroup.get("onSingleSelectionArray") as FormArray;
  }

getValue() {
    console.log(this.onSingleSelectionArray.value);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves lot of my query, but Radio button is not working the way it should be. every radio button is being selected. i want to fetch the only one selected and other should be deselected.

Comment: It's deselected only. if you want to fetch the selected one you do filter the returned value from the formArray.